# Temp table foreach update

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, foreach, temp-tables

I am trying to loop through all records of a generated `temp table` to update the key. The table is combined in multiple steps, the index can only be assigned when the table is compleate.

The problem is that the temp table has `no index` when I want to loop through it, so using the statement `UPDATE tablename WHERE index = value` is useless

Is there a way for me to loop throught the `temp table` and update the current selected record. The id should be `incremented` for each record

Example:

```
IDField     Field1      Field2
0           1           1
0           2           1
0           1           2
0           3           3
```

Loop through each record to change it to:

```
IDField     Field1      Field2
1           1           1
2           2           1
3           1           2
4           3           3
```

Is this possible `without an index`, if show how should I do this?

Comment: what do you mean by when you say loop through each record? SQL Server best works with set based data processing. Also share the code you have written, it can give users a better idea of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @M.Ali The code/table is not the issue. But I'll add a demo table for the idea

Comment: now how do you define which row gets assigned what number? how are you populating this Temp table to begin with?

Comment: I can think of two possible solutions,  1)    if the table is being created with `Create Table` statement then use Identity field to populate this column when the table is being created. 2) if you are creating this table on the fly using `SELECT * INTO #Temp FROM Table` then use `ROW_NUMBER()` in your select statement to give incremental value to this column.

Comment: @M.Ali Thanks! Using ROW_NUMBER solved the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Cursor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx) to loop through your query result. Here is an example of how to loop through `Table_Name` in `SELECT Table_Name FROM Information_Schema.Tables`

```
DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(128)
DECLARE @getTableName CURSOR
SET @getTableName = CURSOR FOR
select Information_SCHEMA.tables.Table_name from Information_SCHEMA.tables
OPEN @getTableName
FETCH NEXT
FROM @getTableName INTO @TableName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    -- Use @TableName the way you need
    FETCH NEXT
    FROM @getTableName INTO @TableName
END
CLOSE @getTableName
DEALLOCATE @getTableName
```

Comment: @Yazabpro Thank you for the response, the comment by M.Ali has solved the problem using the ROW_NUMBER with a select into